# Some PDFs are converted improperly using imagemagick

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I faced with following problem with using ImageMagic. I have Java EE web application which need to make some thumbnails from uploaded PDFs. 3rd party application uploads PDFs to my application.

My application tryes to convert [this PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw4Mp6mHvgJDOEJEMDFrV3l3aUk/edit?usp=sharing) (and others) via following command

```
convert some.pdf  -auto-orient -resize 100x100> some.png
```

As result of convertation I have [this PNG](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw4Mp6mHvgJDRjV3cjdtVGZ5RTg/edit?usp=sharing). I'm trying for 3 days but wasn't able to figure out whats wrong with uploaded PDFs. Other PDFs is converted in correct way. What's wrong with this PDFs and how to convert it right?

*Note*: Imagemagick V6.8.6.6, GhostScript 8.64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading your version of GhostScript should fix the problem. Ghostscript is responsible for creating an image from your PDF file. With the latest version (9.10) a correct image is created.